# How can I use Json.net to populate a model with custom bindings/mappings?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Here's my JSON:

```
{
    "macAddress": "000A959D6816",
    "softwareVersion": "1.2.1.5-UnnecessaryInfo",
    "lastUpdated": "2015-04-03 20:46:40.375 -0500",
    "charging": true
}
```

And using Json.NET, I can do the following in C#:

```
namespace JsonTest
{
    public class Tablet
    {
        public string MacAddress { get; set; }
        public string SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
        public bool Charging { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public void Test()
        {
            var json = "{ ... }"; // filled in with JSON info from above
            var model = new Tablet();
            try
            {
                JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, model);
            }
            catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so good. The code I have here works great. It populates my model object with all the data from the Json. However, I don't really want the `SoftwareVersion` property of my model to be a string; I'd rather have it be an instance of the [System.Version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. In other words, I'd like my `Tablet` class to look more like this:

```
public class Tablet
{
    public string MacAddress { get; set; }
    public Version SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool Charging { get; set; }
}
```

I don't care about the unnecessary info that gets appended on the end of that version string, so I'd like to write some sort of mapper/binder class that examines the version string from the Json, strips off the unnecessary info, and then parses that field into a `Version` object before proceeding to populate my model. I *do* know how to write that individual parsing method; this would do the trick:

```
private static Version ParseVersion(object versionObj)
{
    var pattern = new Regex(@"^[\d.]+");
    var versionString = versionObj.ToString();
    if (!pattern.IsMatch(versionString)) return null;

    var match = pattern.Match(versionString);
    versionString = match.Groups[0].ToString();

    Version version;
    Version.TryParse(versionString, out version);
    return version;
}
```

What I don't know is where and how to "plug this in" during the JsonConvert process. I see that the `PopulateObject` takes an optional [JsonSerializerSettings](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) parameter, and in turn that has several different object initializer parameters like [Binder](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Binder.htm) and [Converters](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm). But I'm not sure which one to use, nor how to write either of those classes to do what I'm describing here. How do I do it? And what is the difference between a Binder and a Converter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an appropriate [`JsonConverterAttribute`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) to your `Version` property, and [`PopulateObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject.htm) will use it:

```
public class Tablet
{
    public string MacAddress { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(VersionConverter))]
    public Version SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool Charging { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the actual converter:

```
public class VersionConverter : JsonConverter 
{
    private static Version ParseVersion(object versionObj)
    {
        var pattern = new Regex(@"^[\d.]+");
        var versionString = versionObj.ToString();
        if (!pattern.IsMatch(versionString)) 
            return null;

        var match = pattern.Match(versionString);
        versionString = match.Groups[0].ToString();

        Version version;
        Version.TryParse(versionString, out version);
        return version;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return  objectType == typeof(System.Version);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        return ParseVersion((string)token);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var version = (Version)value;
        if (version != null)
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

You should now be all set.

Alternatively, if you have a `Version` property appearing in many different container classes in a complex object graph, and you don't want to set the `JsonConverterAttribute` everywhere, you can add your converter to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm), then pass that to [`PopulateObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_PopulateObject_1.htm):

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(json, model, new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter [] { new VersionConverter() } } );
```